# create empty dataframe and error replacement has 1 row, data has 0 occurs

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to create an empty dataframe, and set up columns for appending values later on.

My code:

```
df <- data.frame()

varNames <- c("rho", "lambda", "counts")
colnames(df)<- varNames
df['$rho'] <- NA
df["lambda"] <- NA
df["counts"] <- NA
```

But

> `Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "$rho", value = NA) : replacement has 1 row, data has 0`

occurs.

Comment: You could use `data.frame(rho = numeric(), lambda = numeric(), counts = numeric())`

Comment: You could also do data.frame(rho = NULL, lambda = NULL, counts = NULL)

Comment: FYI, In general, you usually don't need to initialize objects in R prior to looping.

Comment: @Sotos so I can append values directly? For example, I can just write `append(df["rho"], value)` without specifying what `df` is?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Sotos I'm trying to create a dataframe and append R outputs, and eventually write to an excel sheet. That is why I specify the columns.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you need to replace `forloop` with `*apply` and keep results in a *list* from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46398500/680068), then we would not need to create above empty *dataframe* and "grow" it inside the forloop.

Comment: for me it's kind of bug - shouldn't be a problem such usage as in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
df1 <- data.frame(rho = numeric(), lambda = numeric(), counts = numeric()) 
rbind(df1, list(rho = NA, lambda = NA, counts = NA))
#  rho lambda counts
#1  NA     NA     NA
```

---

If we are assigning separately, then a `list` would be useful

```
lst <- setNames(vector("list", 3), varNames)
lst[['rho']] <- NA
lst[['lambda']] <- NA
lst
#$rho
#[1] NA

#$lambda
#[1] NA

#$counts
#NULL
```

as `list` elements can be of different `length` whereas a `data.frame` is a `list` with equal length columns.  Once the assignments are completed and are of equal lengths, then convert it to data.frame with `data.frame(lst)` and write it back to file

Comment: @Kay What is the objective here

Comment: it works with the `rbind`, but not with the code in my question, where I add 3 columns separately with value `NA`. Do you know why it occurs? I'm trying to create a dataframe and append R outputs, and eventually write to an excel sheet. That is why I specify the columns.

Comment: @Kay  If you want to add it separately, then use a `list` instead of `data.frame` as `data.frame` is a `list` with equal length columns